# LINQ to Entities attaching and detaching foreign key entities

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-entities, asp.net-3.5

I am currently using LINQ and the Entity Framework to do my database connection layer.  In my database I have a `Files` table and a `Products` table. I also have a `ProductHasFiles` table that joins the 2 in a many to many relationship.

My issue is this.  I have a single file loaded in my context and I have a list of `Product` IDs that I need to either attach or detach from to the file record.  How do I do that?

I know I can get all of the current Products attached to the File by doing `File.Product.Load();` but how do I detach them once I do this?  Also, is there a way to attach existing Products without loading the whole Product entry?  I already have the ID so I hope that would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add or remove object without retrieving it, use stub entities: [How to delete an object without retrieving it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-9-how-to-delete-an-object-without-retrieving-it). Create stub, add to context, add to file.Products.

Why do you want to detach after loading?